# How to make a List resizable by user

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm experimenting with SwiftUI in MacOS and I'm developing a simple application. I'm not sure how to make a VStack the one with the "Hello World" list inside, resizable by the end-user. I can't figure out what kind of artifact I need to make it work like should be.

This is my code so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: CGFloat(200.0), maxWidth: CGFloat(400.0))
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            List(0 ..< 3) { item in
                Text("Content")
            }
        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry my dude. Try out this library [PartitionKit Resizable UI Partitions](https://github.com/kieranb662/PartitionKit)

Comment: I have tested it, and while it looks very promising. I see is there is in a very early state